# "Can't create or write into directory" ownCloud MySql error

Tags: mysql, debian, raspberry-pi

I installed owncloud 7.0.3 on a Raspberry Pi per instructions given in the admin manual. I then created an external folder under /media/owncloud/data on an USB drive. And moved /var/www/owncloud/data directory to this directory. Then I set up the ownership of this directory by (all after setting sudo -i at $ prompt)

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /media/owncloud/data/
```

and also did

```
chmod -R 0777 /media/owncloud/data/
```

But

```
stat ./data
```

reports

```
File: `./data'
Size: 4096          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 72          Links: 1
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/      pi)   Gid: ( 1000/      pi)
Access: 2014-11-29 14:06:05.328198000 -0500
Modify: 2014-11-29 13:27:25.436161000 -0500
Change: 2014-11-29 13:27:25.436161000 -0500
```

Therefore when I try to login to owncloud on my browser I get

```
"Can't create or write into the data directory /media/owncloud/data
```

How can I make the ./data directory writable so that owncloud starts successfully?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: This is exactly the problem that I'm having now.